# Can you create a multidemensional array with a stack of Dicom images in Objective C?

Tags: arrays, objective-c, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I am working on a plugin for Horos with the goal of gathering a stack of dicom images in a folder, converting the dicom image into a 3D array, with the x and y axes as the height and width of the resolution, 256x256, and the z axis as the number of images in the stack. I was wondering on how I would be able to do this? Any guidance will help.

Thank you!

Edit: I specifically would like to take the pixel value from each pixel in the 256x256 dicom and put that into the array. I am then aiming to repeat this process for however many images that are in the folder/stack.

Comment: On SO, the procedure is to try something and post it, allow the community to suggest edits / fixes.  Here's what you should try: declare a scalar array like this `NSUInteger pixels[256][256];` and get/set locations with `pixels[x][y]`

Comment: @danh Thank you for the advice! I will try your recommendation. If I need help after trying, I will post what I have done with it as well. Thank you for letting me know on how to use SO as well.

Comment: Just a remark: I've been working for about 20 years in the DICOM/PACS field, so let me tell you that this is no fun area. DICOM is a collection of legacy deviations from the so-called standard, you will simply lose your nerve. Putting data into a 3d-array is _nothing_ compared to that complexity. I can't even start with what the problems are, it's just annoying.